# In regard to the overriding methods, is the code using two derived classes legal?

Tags: java, oop, overriding

For example:

```
public class example {
    public class A {
            public void speak() {
                    System.out.println("Hello!");
            }
  }

    public class B extends A {
            public void response() {
                    System.out.println("How are you?");
            }
  }

    public class C extends A {
            public void responseTwo() {
                    System.out.println("Good!");
  }
}
```

A test1 = new A(); // it's legal.

A test2 = new B(); // it's also legal.

B test3 = new C(); // not legal. Why is that?

Comment: What do you mean by identical?

Comment: What do you mean with `the same program` ? Same class or .. ?

Comment: You can define classes in same source file but you cannot make them all public. Only one class can be public and name of file should be same as that of public class. And what do youo mean by idential?

Comment: They are not identical, they have different names

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I fixed it.

Comment: I like this question.

Comment: Please stop approving edits that completely change what is being asked.

Comment: Please, see my response ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of that classes are RIGHT. You cannot declare more than one public class in a file, but you can declare public classes inside other class. But you can only use them in your class in which they are declared.

This is illegal because B and C are diferents classes. See:

```
A test1 = new A(); // it's legal.

A test2 = new B(); // it's also legal.

B test3 = new C(); // not legal. Why is that?**
```

You are assigning an object of type C to a variable of type B. They are "brothers" not parent/child classes.

You can do:

```
A test = new C();
```

Your classes hierachy are like this:

```
    A
----|----
|       |
B       C
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's some information you haven't shared that should be fine since `B` and `C` have distinct names. They may have the same fields or not; it doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? The two classes can have different methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean in the same source file. The answer is NO.
(Compiler will warn you with the following message : *The public type B must be defined in its own file* or *The public type C must be defined in its own file*)

You can define inner classes though, as below :

```
public class A {
    //blah blah blah

    public class B extends A {
        //blah blah blah
    }

    public class C extends A {
        //blah blah blah
    }

}
```

Comment: you mean: in the same *source* file. Each class will have a dedicated file, in your example (A.java): A.class, A$B.class, A$C.class.

Answer (score 0):

All of these classes should have their own "file"

Is you are using Eclipse it's basically making a new class.

Unless there is any information that you haven't shared with us.

You can't just put multiple classes in the same "file" (class file)

You need to create separate class files for each class you wish to have in your program.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "same program"?

You can create multiple classes within same FILE with .java extension, but only one class will be allowed to be public, for example:

```
public class A {

}

class B extends A{


}

class C extends B{

}
```

and filename should be the one with public modifier in this case it will be A.java

Comment: public class A is not a file. It's actually a method inside example.java class.

Comment: @Shuvo0o are you talking about method overloading?

Comment: first of all A is not just method, it is special method known as constructor. :)

Comment: Yeah and overriding methods

Comment: Here what you are doing is called as "Constructor Overloading". and you can have more than one method with same name with different "Method Signature", by method signature i mean 1. Number of arguments 2. Type of arguments 3. Order of arguments

I think you were looking for this answer?

Comment: for method overridding go through this tutorial. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm

Comment: Another question: 
     A x1 = new A(); // it's legal. 
     A x2 = new B(); // it's also legal. 
     B x3 = new C(); // not legal. Why is that?

Comment: Because B and C are different classes, simply

Comment: in your edited question, B is a sub-class of A, C is the sub-class of A, you can create object of A with **reference** of B(as it is sub-class of A) but object of B can not be created with **reference** of C as they are different.